# Gaussian Process as a time series model, pros and cons

Tags: time-series, arima, gaussian-process, kriging

When talkin' about time series models, ARIMA, SARIMAX, Prophet or VAR is what mostly is on the table. But what would the benefit be of using a Gaussian Process Regressor instead, in which situations could such a model be a good choice? And in which situations is it definitely not a good idea to go forward with?

Comment: I suppose one of the benefits would be a covariance matrix that is easy to understand. For example if one had a good intuition that a Gaussian kernel function $\text{Cov}(x_i,x_j)=\exp(-(x_i-x_j)^2/2)$ was appropriate then using a Gaussian Process framework lets you very easily implement this. One thing I would say is that for many standard time series models, when fitting them you end up assuming the errors are iid Gaussian so the final model of the data is a Gaussian Process

Comment: One search-word to use is *kriging*, see for instance https://www.czso.cz/documents/10180/45606527/32019717q1059.pdf/11fd31c1-1760-4366-a2a5-168167614694?version=1.0